# How to test J and B type RISCV instructions with random operands jumping to random memory locations?

Tags: assembly, simulation, riscv, machine-code, verilator

I am using Verilator to simulate Ibex RISCV core.

I have written a RISCV random instruction generator, which simply randomly generates RISCV instructions with random operands as well. All these generated instructions together compose a small assembly program.

This means the generator will absolutely generate J type and B type instructions with a large offset that leads to a very far memory location that exceeds the boundary of the program, where there is literally no valid instruction at all. And the processor does not know that so it keeps fetching illegal instructions after that destination address, which results in failed simulation. For example:

```
  f0:   77c00f13                li      t5,1916
  f4:   00000013                nop
  f8:   00271a93                slli    s5,a4,0x2
  fc:   da500ce3                beq     zero,t0,ffffff14 <__global_pointer$+0xffffe5a0>
 100:   0067dab3                srl     s5,a5,t1
 104:   00f19933                sll     s2,gp,a5
 108:   d55e2023                sw      s5,-704(t3)
 10c:   5504f113                andi    sp,s1,1360
```

let's assume the final instruction of this program is `andi` at the address of `0x10c`. If `beq` at address `0xfc` is true, pc is updated to a value that is outside this program (before or after, both can happen).

In this case, what am I supposed to do to prevent the processor fetching illegal instructions outside the memory region of this program? My plan is to make it fetch the instruction at `0x100` right after executing `beq` (same for other J and B type instuctions) instead of in other memory regions.

Comment: Can you treat a taken branch outside the code block as a successful end of the test? (After verifying that it was the correct jump target address, and that it was reached with the correct architectural state (register values, stores and uncacheable loads having happened, etc.)

Comment: Make sure you take into account that there's a difference between failed test and failed execution.  Some execution should result in failure of the processor to proceed, i.e. the processor taking an exception, such as: `ecall` (unless emulated), such as misaligned load (when not supported), such as load/store of reserved or out of bounds memory, and branch to non-existent address.  These things should stop the processor via an exception and that is the proper behavior, so should be able to write tests that cause exceptions, that succeed as tests.

Comment: Of course not only large offsets are problematic, in fact a jump to anywhere can be. A jump to itself will result in an endless loop for example.